# Bash .sh file variable scope

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu

I am attempting to create an associative array for constants for a shell session using 2 files, one a main array, the second file having values specific to the environment for example Ubuntu or OSX.

To test these currently contain:

**main.sh**

```
declare -A ddops;
ddops[main]='test val';
```

**os.sh**

```
ddops[os]='osx';
```

The aim is to setup via a url so running a script using

```
bash <(curl -s https://somegiturlwhichshowstobeaccessibleandexecute);
```

which contains

```
./mainenv.sh;
./osenv.sh;
```

however when testing from the terminal empty output is given

```
echo ${ddops[main]};
echo ${ddops[os]};
```

I think this may be a scope issue, how can I declare this array to go to into the shell and become accessible ?

For clarity curl executes correctly to create mainenv.sh and osenv.sh containing the code as above.
Execution of these files is done within the directory they are saved into.

Comment: What is the output of `curl`? Where do `mainenv.sh` and `osenv.sh` live?

Comment: edited for clarity, output creates the files from urls and shown as successful as they are indeed created. mainenv and osenv are chmod to 777 and execution is from within the directory they are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption of a scope issue, I proceeded with compiling all into a single file (bashcompile) and then `cp`ied it to `.bash_profile`, reloading with `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Testing as above was then successful.